# element.style.fontSize does not return size

Tags: javascript

I'm so defeated I'm prepared to suffer any abuse to find out why I can't do something as simple as get the onload function to tell me the body font size is 20pt.  I've read till my eyes bleed, and everyone but me seems able to make the script below work.

But my #@!/%#! code vomits an alert box with the following:(I used two lines to be sure it wasn't a case problem)

```
[  ]
[undefined]
```

Actually, my goal was to use scritp that executed in the head section, or onload, to read the screen width, and set the body font size by formula.  [Next try will be to leave the body tag out of the code, and have the script document.write() in a body tag with style specs that sets the body font size.  This below was supposed to just be a warm up exercise.] Any and all help is appreciated.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {font-size:20pt;color:white;font-weight:bold;background:grey;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      onload=function(){
        alert("[ " + document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize +" ]"
           +"\n[ " + document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontsize + " ]");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Test Text</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following s is as far as I got with the help of comments below.

These both return font size.

```
getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize
getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('font-size')
```

But they throw errors when used to set font size

```
getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize = "30pt";
getComputedStyle(document.body).setProperty("fontSize", "25pt", "important") ;
```

On the other hand, these both set new font size

```
document.body.style.fontSize = "200%";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize = "400%";
```

But they both return a string of lenght 0 when asked for font size.

```
document.body.style.fontSize 
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize
```

Here's an onload function to confirm it with:

```
 onload=function(){
   var msg = "onload:\n";
   /* these both return font size.*/
   msg += "1. [ " + getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize + "]\n";
   msg += "2. [ " + getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('font-size') + "]\n";
   /* these both return a string of lenght 0.*/
   msg += "3. [ " + document.body.style.fontSize + "]\n"; 
   msg += "4. [ " + document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize + "]\n"; 
     /*these both throw errors*/
     try { getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize = "30pt";
   } catch (err) { msg += "5. [" + err.message + "]\n"; }
   try {getComputedStyle(document.body).setProperty("fontSize", "25pt", "important") ;
   } catch (err) { msg += "6. [" + err.message + "]\n"; }
   /*these both set new font size*/
   alert(msg);
   document.body.style.fontSize = "200%";
   setTimeout(function(){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize = "400%"},1500);
 }
```

There is obviously something I'm missing, but for now this works.
Merry Christmas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can just use `document.body` instead of having to use `getElementsByTagName`.
2. `fontsize` is improper capitalization; that's why your second alert is returning `undefined`.
3. If you want the font size of an element *as specified by CSS*, you have to use `getComputedStyle`:

   ```
   alert(getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
   // => "20pt"
   ```

   See [the MDN docs for `getComputedStyle` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: That works.  I'm just not sure what object the getComputedStyle() method is called on.  From above lack of reference I would have guessed window, but now that you provided the method name I find references to it as document.getComputedStyle().  I guess W3schools web site list of the document object methods isn't up to date, because it doesn't list it.  That's a prob for another day.  For now a great and simple solution.  Thank you.

Comment: @George It's a property of `window` (as shown in the doc link I have posted). Please *never* use W3Schools! See http://w3fools.com. MDN is a much better resource (which is, again, linked in my answer).

Comment: For those who follow:  The above is great advice.  So I can return to my initital problem - dynamically adjust body font size onresize.  getComputedStyle() returns CSSStyleDeclaration.  Per MDN it has a setProperty() method I hope works.  But ... when I click on that method on the MDN web site, I get NOT FOUND.  But if it works, I'll be back to post the solution.  I've seen this general issue disscussed at higher levels everywhere, but I think a simple complete examample might help starters like me.  Thanks again.

Comment: @George Once you have the font size and you have changed it to whatever you want, you can use `document.body.style.fontSize` to set it; no need to use `getComputedStyle` here.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot read CSS. What you need to do is define your font-size inline so Javascript can understand it. When you type:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize
```

It is referring first to the element in the DOM. Style is an attribute of that element, and when using a stylesheet styling is formatted differently, not as an attribute. So what you need to do is:

```
<body style='font-size:20px'>
<!-- content -->
</body>
```

Comment: `Window.getComputedStyle()` queries CSS properties